# Google reCaptcha validation on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, recaptcha

I am implementing reCaptcha in my website, but i could not validate recaptcha on form submit. The form is getting submitted even if the recaptcha is not clicked. How to check whether the captcha is valid/checked or not The code snippet is :

```
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                     <div class="input-group"> 
                                          <input id="mailid" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="form-control input-md" required>
                                        </div>
                                      <br>
                                    </div>

                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site-key" id="recaptcha"></div> <br>   
                    <div class="btn-group">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Button1" /><h5>submit</h5> 
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" id="cancelbtn" /><u><a href = "login.html">cancel </a></u>

                </div>
                </form>
```

NOTE : We are not using php in the application.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450562/how-to-validate-google-recaptcha-on-form-submit