# Validating submit of form with Google reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, html, validation, captcha, recaptcha

I've had a look at this question

[How to Validate Google reCaptcha on Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450562/how-to-validate-google-recaptcha-on-form-submit)

And tried to implement the answer of that question into my code to validate my form so that it won't submit if the captcha hasn't been completed.

However nothing happens - it just submits the form.

this is my code:

```
 <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
      'sitekey' : 'my_site_key'
    });
  };
</script>

 </head>

          <div id="html_element"></div>
      <br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction">

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer>
function myFunction() {    
if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "")
    alert("You can't proceed!");
else
    alert("Thank you");}
 </script>
```

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
    'sitekey' : 'site-key'
  });
};
onloadCallback();

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You can't proceed!");
  } else {
    alert("Thank you");
  }
});
           </script>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="html_element"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer>

 </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: I don't follow your code at all. What event is supposed to be triggering the IF statement?

Comment: Okay so I forgot to wrap the IF statement in a function, check my edit above

Comment: That won't work either. I've posted a working answer below.

Comment: A bit late to this. Lol. But you need to make sure the JS only runs after the page has rendered. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to trigger your `if` statement in an **event**. If you're using jQuery you can do this very easily:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You can't proceed!");
  } else {
    alert("Thank you");
  }
});
```

See working example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/gu90b2ef/)

The problem with doing this in JavaScript at all is that the user can easily fake the result if they want to. If you really want to be checking if the user is a robot or not, you should still be comparing the result submitted by the user (via POST) on the server side using your reCAPTCHA secret key.

Comment: This is just an additional part of the form, the secret key will still be getting used. 
However, this still isnt working for me, I've added your JSFiddle code into a new document and can't fathom it out. Will you have a look at my latest edit above where I have added my new code.

Comment: Thanks. it worked with google captcha 2 version. Voted.