# Google ReCaptcha Display with Image & Client Side Validation on Form Submit

Tags: php, validation, client-side, recaptcha

I have followed

[How to Validate Google reCaptcha on Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450562/how-to-validate-google-recaptcha-on-form-submit)

I have below code in my **index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="post.php">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6XXXXXXXXXXXXwdsf0K8HbXXXXXXX"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**post.php**

```
$response = $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$secret = '6XXXXXXXXXXXXwdsf0K8HbJNvMw-XXXX';
$server = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secret . "&response=" . $response.'&remoteip='.$server);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
if ($response["success"] === true) {
    echo "Logged In Successfully";
} else {
    echo "You are a robot";
}
exit;
```

Above code is working fine.

**How to do client side validation? It's not showing Captcha with Images Option.**

[image]

I already done below

[image]

Comment: your post.php is doing the clinet side validation?

Comment: wel i dont really know what your asking.

Comment: Hi @nogad Before Form Submit, i would like to do Client Side Validation Clear? Using jQuery

Comment: ok, what are you validating? what does reCAPTCHA have to do with it?

Comment: Example: Suppose we have First Name in Form. So through jQuery we are validating that `This is required field` same like. So before click on `Submit` button & go to server side on client side it will be required fields Hope it clear your doubts

Comment: ok well nothing you have posted in the question has anything to do with that.

Comment: Please check `How to do client side validation? It's not showing Captcha with Images Option.` in Question

Comment: Have you checked your browser's error log for any hints?

Comment: No error/Logs @ChristianF

Comment: so you want recaptcha to show image test everytime?

Comment: It's not going to show images right?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: No not found still

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard behavior of the Recaptcha library does not display the first time the control over the images.

Try to view or post the page many times and you will see that the images not eventually appear.

If you want to do some client side validation on other additionnals fields, you must use jQuery or standar library like bootstrap or foundation, like [this](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/) or [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/abide.html). You can see of full example of a working script here (inspired from bootstrap script and HTML 5 capabilities) :

This version of the script is the same all over Internet. No more client side validation for this ! Have a look to a reference : [codepen.io signup](https://codepen.io/signup/free)

For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
      <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="signin-form" method="post" action="post.php">
            <!-- for example : Email and password validation (HTML 5) -->
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <!-- Site-key for automated tests -->
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And [here](http://codepen.io/weenesta/pen/rWVWEm) a sample code pen.

Comment: Have you got time to test ?