# Contact Form submits without checking reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm making a webapp with a contact form, and have a google reCAPTCHA (v2) on my website to prevent robot-spam.

I have added this code to the website:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>


<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

When I try to submit my form, I'm able to submit it without the reCAPTCHA being used.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that anything is wrong here? At least in v3, this should be the standard behaviour

Comment: @NicoHaase So when someone goes to click "submit" after they filled out the form, the form should be sent even if they haven't passed the reCAPTCHA?

Comment: What exactly makes you think that someone submitting the form has not passed the captcha process? In v3, this does not require any manual interaction

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm using V2, I don't like V3

Comment: no one liking v3, as the users or admins cant see it working in front, they dont trust it.

Comment: @galzor very true.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following little jquery code to check if user is trying to submit the form without clicking the recaptcha.

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
   var recaptcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
   if (recaptcha === "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Please check the recaptcha");
   }
});
```

furthermore you can use the below code to make api call to check if the response is valid. In case the User has validated himself, the response will be a very long string.

```
if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == ""){
    alert("You can't proceed!");
} else {
    alert("Thank you");
}
```

take a look here [How to Validate Google reCaptcha on Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450562/how-to-validate-google-recaptcha-on-form-submit) for more information on how to validate recaptcha.

Comment: I added this code, but it still gives me the option to submit without validating or using reCAPTCHA

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Galzor said you need to implement a server side verification as described here  https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Steps are following:

- add reCaptcha widget to the form you want to protect, use public key when you register widget (you should have it from console https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create when you registered reCaptcha)
- when you submit form, in javascript, check that capcha is solved by checking $("#g-recaptcha-response") input field for a long hashstring (token)
- when your form submitted, on the server side, before processing anything, you need to call google Recaptcha Api with the Secret (private key from the console too) and verify response.

If you do not implement a server side verification a bot can add something looking as a normal response to the #g-recaptcha-response input and pass the client side validation. That also means it's not enough just check on the server or client side that input is not empty - You need to call ReCaptcha API and check it's response if the token is valid (Google provides ready library for php)

Comment: This is super helpful. Google's documentation is not. Thanks!