# recaptcha v2 not working in html via DreamWeaver

Tags: recaptcha, dreamweaver

I have a contact form in html via DreamWeaver, and I have inserted recaptcha v2 in the form.  Two things are not working.  1. The form can be submitted without clicking the recaptcha box.  2. if the box is clicked, I get a message saying I submitted a gibberish word (see below).  how do I fix the code?

You have submitted a gibberish word: "03aiiukzg-7r-qryb1oca4e2zq0vhiehwkzfahzyxju8mayz36qmixfz1yr_cgec1ctjovccj6ymjuyuhtr8a0eetzo6vdq8l22x8fs1mqpce5zafgqhji4ez75cfcqfsgn6tvn5xajglypg5e0g-jgpwrqjrebgbtup40hyk99qrvh_ax-ewuvabcyvz1igdj785wvhlo_tnkjujbkbmtghibs4hmvlcez7qvymjttqxy97q8zhqf0v0nipjqetcwmju0xqmvswins8fekhchmxjpulb5rje4ef-ar6vxltxh0ktkxmgnlivhzswf_haq5hcdyqucnpqgmybantcekhqf0t6wj-e3faadozatd-ynbnzfgwsejjf-1vmvtbrvzfyjxhi8cfxmflqjc-idxmocqubivu3q6cop7mve7c7voo8xbrfyfgwbnlwgyczsn9oksufjvsn_us8kozd2ycg2ezadhcaegqtsfuns2i4w7wp64cmxin-e0s_lsoe8or8jqrqhwkrheqcaffh-jfyqp0tujgshd4bncnzbywg6estbdrhngtutiv9a6oyomqi5lavh9szl"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contact Form submits without checking reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160821/contact-form-submits-without-checking-recaptcha)

Comment: Please have a look at the other question. Without any code it is nearly impossible to help you.